# How to hide a contenttype listing page from users?

Tags: bolt-cms

In Bolt dashboard, I could set the status of any instance of my `contenttype` to Draft, which would hide the page from users. However, the listing page would still be visible to the public. Is there a way to hide the contenttype entirely from the users?

Answer (score 0):

In the `contenttypes.yml` file you can set the parameter

```
viewless: true
```

against the specific contenttype and that will disable frontend views for this contenttype. What the user will see when they hit the url `/entries` will be a standard 404 page.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do this by excluding the contenttype from the sitemap.xml.